# Proper way of coding

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new in developing android applications. I want to create an android application(using eclipse) which needs a login page where the user needs to put his/her username and password and when the username and password is correct the application will open the main page. I already made a layout for the login page. My question is, is it proper to put the function codes of login and main page in the same package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would define a Login Activity which handles all the Login action, save it in preferences etc and then have it start the MAIN activity when the user is logged in.

Comment: thank you. I've read your profile and found out that your an Android Engineer. I would just like to ask if I can ask you questions about creating android applications. I'm new to this and I am currently studying in creating android applications.

Comment: We are all here to help, but the best way to learn still is: Read the Examples, get the documentation, learn how to use the docs, then come back here for problems.. and most importantly use google.

Answer (score 0):

yes if they are meant to ship together that'll be easiest

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no problem in putting the login code and code for the main activity in the same package.

However, to provide the login functionality, you should ask the user login credentials the first time. On successful authentication, you should save it either in your database or in Preferences (preferable). I myself save the authentication details in a preference file. You can even encrypt the saved details if you are too much conscious.

So the next time when the user tries to run your app requiring authentication, it should first check as to whether the credentials are saved in database/Preferences.. if yes, then use those details for login, else perform fresh authentication.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Mahendra Liya.